# How can we install Inform in Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, dependencies

How can this package be installed? Inform ([inform7](http://inform7.com/)) is an Interactive Fiction editor available for many platforms. A `.deb` package is available for many distros and architectures, including Squeeze packaged for Gnome.

There is a dependency in this package that cannot be satisfied:

> Dependency is not satisfiable: libwebkit-1.0-2 (>= 1.1.1)

Debian Jessie has migrated to `libwebkitgtk`.

Editing the Debian/Control file to change the dependency has not enabled installation of the `.deb`.  The I7_6G60_Linux_all.tar.gz package has a very poor GUI, so isn't desirable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try downloading [`libwebkit` from the `squeeze` repo](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libwebkit-1.0-2) and seeing if you can install it without too much dependency faff.  Scroll to the bottom of that page to find the download links.

Comment: Thanks, but is the version of libwebkit available from that link high enough? It states  libwebkit-1.0-2 (though it elsewhere states 1.2.7-0+squeeze2, whatever this means)?

Comment: I *think* that file will satisfy your dependency but I'm not sure -- try it :)

Comment: It does not work: Dependency is not satisfiable: libicu44 (>= 4.4.1-1)

Comment: Try `apt-get install libicu44` and do this for each failed dependency... or, failing that, try to install a `squeeze` package from http://packages.debian.org/ -- you might find yourself disappearing down an endless rabbit warren, but if you're lucky there'll only be a few to deal with.

Comment: Thanks again, but it didn't work. Dependency is not satisfiable: libicu44 (>= 4.4.1-1)